# simple Issue with action script 2.0 about a button

Tags: actionscript-2

Could someone please help me make this code work.

(I want to put this code in a movieclip)

on roll over a button a movieclip keeps going to the right.

on roll out of the button the movieclip stops.

if (rollOver(_root.Rbutton)) {
_x += speed;

this is what i got so far.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is homework type question, with no effort shown from OP

Comment: I'm actually working on a school project. I explained the issue in a simple way so I can use this as reference in my project thats why no effort was shown. thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button and the movieClip are on the stage of your main timeline:

```
var xspeed:Number = 2;

function mcToMove():Void {
    mc._x += xspeed;
}

myButton.onRollOver = function():Void {
    onEnterFrame = mcToMove;
}

myButton.onRollOut = function():Void {
    delete onEnterFrame;
}
```